# Postgresql equivalent of an Access autonumber field

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to build a database for my company and my programmer does not know how to have a number which fills itself in like in Access 2003. In Access, you can have auto number with a field and it will insert for you.  How do you do this in Postgresql?  My programmer needs help, and he cannot find a book on it. Thanks very much!

Comment: It's also quite voluminous and it's not always obvious where to look.

Comment: @Wayne: then again, programming in any language without at least scanning through the docs once is not the smartest thing...

Comment: @Denis, It is often the smartest thing.  My work spans many languages and disciplines.  My employer doesn't pay me to become an expert in all of them, but to get the job done.  "Scanning the docs" is reserved for languages and programs that I'll be using enough that the time spent will be paid back.  For the rest, there is google, and when that fails, sites like this.

Answer (score 10):

Postgresql documentation: [8.1.4. Serial Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

The data types `serial` and `bigserial` are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases).